# Find the number of occurence of a string in multiple files

Tags: linux, unix, sed, grep

I would like to count the number of occurence of a particular string  . I am using the following command.The string may appear for multiple times in the same line. Could someone please help me on this.

i`m using the following command

```
sed 's/STRING/STRING\n/g' filename | grep -c "STRING"
```

I`m getting the following output
**Output :**

100

**Expected output :**

```
filename 100
```

Also could someone help me how i can run the code in multiple files in a folder and get a output similar to the below

**Output:**

filename  100

filename2 300

filename3 200

Answer (score 1):

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -lne '$c++ while /STRING/g; print(0+$c, " $ARGV"), $c=0 if eof' *
```

Answer (score 0):

With the shell plus `grep` and `wc` you could do the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Iterate over files in the current directory
for file in * ; do

    # Skip directories
    if [ -d "$file" ] ; then
        continue
    fi

    # Print the filename
    echo -n "$file "

    # grep -o prints every match on a separate line
    # wc -l counts the lines
    grep -o 'STRING' "$file" | wc -l

done
```